How to Configure Echidna to Access Node Modules in a Hardhat Project?
I'm setting up Echidna to fuzz test a Solidity project managed by Hardhat, and I need Echidna to access dependencies in node_modules. Here’s my project structure:
/Users/codertjay/GolandProjects/2024-11-telcoin-codertjay/telcoin-audit
├── contracts
├── node_modules
├── echidna.config.yaml
├── hardhat.config.ts
└── ...

I understand that I can use solcArgs in echidna.config.yaml to set allowed paths. My current echidna.config.yaml looks like this:
yaml
Copy code
testMode: "property"
solcArgs: "--allow-paths .,node_modules"
contractAddr: "0x00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72"
deployer: "0x30000"
sender:
  - "0x10000"
  - "0x20000"
coverage: true

I’d like to confirm:
Currently i still get the error
  telcoin-audit git:(main) ✗ echidna  contracts/echidna/EchidnaStablecoin.sol --config echidna.config.yaml

[2024-11-07 10:52:57.09] Compiling contracts/echidna/EchidnaStablecoin.sol... Done! (0.579834s)
echidna: Couldn't compile given file
stdout:
stderr:
INFO:CryticCompile:'solc --version' running
INFO:CryticCompile:'solc contracts/echidna/EchidnaStablecoin.sol --combined-json abi,ast,bin,bin-runtime,srcmap,srcmap-runtime,userdoc,devdoc,hashes --allow-paths .,/Users/codertjay/GolandProjects/2024-11-telcoin-codertjay/telcoin-audit/contracts/echidna' running
ERROR:CryticCompile:Invalid solc compilation Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20PermitUpgradeable.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> contracts/echidna/EchidnaStablecoin.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import {ERC20PermitUpgradeable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20PermitUpgradeable.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20PermitUpgradeable.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> contracts/stablecoin/Stablecoin.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import {ERC20PermitUpgradeable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20PermitUpgradeable.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> contracts/stablecoin/Stablecoin.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import {SafeERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/StorageSlot.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> contracts/stablecoin/Stablecoin.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import {StorageSlot} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/StorageSlot.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/AccessControlUpgradeable.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> contracts/util/abstract/Blacklist.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import {AccessControlUpgradeable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/AccessControlUpgradeable.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^



i just did echidna . and it seems it works seems i was targeting a specific contract that why i was getting the error.
